# Ansible, iterate over multiple registers and make extended use of build in methods

Tags: ansible

To start off I have all my variables defined in YAML

```
app_dir: "/mnt/{{ item.name }}"
app_dir_ext: "/mnt/{{ item.0.name }}"
workstreams:
  - name: tigers
    service_workstream: tigers-svc
    app_sub_dir:
      - inbound
      - inbound/incoming
      - inbound/error
      - inbound/error/processed
  - name: lions
    service_workstream: lions-svc
    app_sub_dir:
      - inbound
      - inbound/incoming
      - inbound/error
      - inbound/error/processed
```

You may note `app_dir: "/mnt/{{ item.name }}"` and `app_dir_ext: "/mnt/{{ item.0.name }}"` looking odd, so I originally had my variables set as below in YAML but decided to use the above mainly due to less lines in YAML when I have a large amount of workstreams.

```
workstreams:
  - name: tigers
    service_workstream: tigers-svc
    app_dir: /mnt/tigers
    ...
```

I then have Ansible code to check if the directories exists, if not create them and apply permissions (!note, have taken this approach due to a ssh timeout on operation when using the `file:` module on a number of very big NFS mounted shares).

```
- name: Check workstreams app_dir
  stat:
    path: "{{ app_dir }}"
  register: app_dir_status
  with_items:
    - "{{ workstreams }}"

- name: Check workstreams app_sub_dir
  stat:
    path: "{{ app_dir_ext }}/{{ item.1 }}/"
  register: app_sub_dir_status
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ workstreams }}"
    - app_sub_dir

- name: create workstreams app_dir
  file:
    path: "/mnt/{{ item.0.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "ftp"
    group: "ftp"
    mode: '0770'
    recurse: yes
  with_nested:
    - '{{ workstreams }}'
    - app_dir_status.results
  when: 
    - '{{ item.1.stat.exists }} == false'
```

This is a little hacky but works, however I have a 2nd, 3rd, 4th path to check..etc

My question here is how to I update/refactor the above code to use `<register_name>.stat.exists == false` from both `app_dir_status` and `app_sub_dir_status` to control my task ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make nested loop! There's all required data inside `app_sub_dir_status` – just strip unnecessary items.

Here's simplified example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_list:
      - name: zzz1
        sub:
          - aaa
          - ccc
      - name: zzz2
        sub:
          - aaa
          - bbb
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /tmp/{{ item.0.name }}/{{ item.1 }}
      register: stat_res
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_list }}"
        - sub
    - debug:
        msg: "path to create '{{ item }}'"
      with_items: "{{ stat_res.results | rejectattr('stat.exists') | map(attribute='invocation.module_args.path') | list }}"
```

You can iterate over `stat_res.results | rejectattr('stat.exists') | list` as well, but will have to construct path again as `/tmp/{{ item.item.0.name }}/{{ item.item.1 }}` – note double `item`, because first `item` is an element of `stat_res.results` which contain another `item` as element of your original loop for stat task.

P.S. Also I see no reason for your first task, as subdir task can detect all missing directories.